# How to create a table with a column which is another table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm a newbie to mysql. I knew this is a very basic question, but I could not figure out how :( ?
My initial attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE Node(  
  Id INT( 3 ),  
  Position VARCHAR( 12 ),  
  FoodTax INT( 2 ),  
  HasTreasureMap TINYINT( 1 ),  
  CurrentPlayer Player, 
  PRIMARY KEY( Id ) 
);
```

In this case, 'Player' is another table that I want to add. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add Tables inside tables, what you do is add a foreign key reference, which is basically the ID (or whatever the PRIMARY KEY is) of the other table and make the other table separately.

```
CREATE TABLE Node (  
  Id INT( 3 ),  
  Position VARCHAR( 12 ),  
  FoodTax INT( 2 ),  
  HasTreasureMap TINYINT( 1 ),  
  CurrentPlayer INT( 3 ),
  PRIMARY KEY( Id ),
  INDEX ( CurrentPlayer )
);

CREATE TABLE Player (
  Id INT( 3 ),
  Name VARCHAR( 64 ),
  PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
);
```

Note that `INDEX( CurrentPlayer )` in the first table is not necessary unless you are going to join the tables, or use the `CurrentPlayer` field to search or sort on.

If you are using the **InnoDB** database engine, then you can directly specify the nature of the relationship between the tables within the definition for the `Node` table as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE Node (  
  Id INT( 3 ),  
  Position VARCHAR( 12 ),  
  FoodTax INT( 2 ),  
  HasTreasureMap TINYINT( 1 ),  
  CurrentPlayer INT( 3 ),
  PRIMARY KEY( Id ),
  INDEX ( CurrentPlayer ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( CurrentPlayer ) REFERENCES Player( Id )
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

The `FOREIGN KEY` addition causes a few effects, it adds a check in so that you can not set a value for `CurrentPlayer` in the `Node` table that does not *already* exist in the `Player` table, any `INSERT/UPDATE` attempting this would fail.  Also, the two options `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` tell the database that if a record from `Player` is updated or deleted, then perform an action automatically via a *trigger* on the `Node` table.  `ON UPDATE CASCADE` means that if the `Id` of a `Player` record was updated to something else, it would *cascade* in to the `Node` table, changing that value too.  `ON DELETE SET NULL` states that if a record is deleted from the `Player` table, then corresponding `CurrentPlayer` values in `Node` should be set to `NULL`.

Comment: Hi Orbling, thanks for your reply. I have 400 nodes but I have only 4 players. So does it make sense to add Player as a foreign key? This is a game map, I want to check whether there is a player in a current node. I'm thinking to keep it in my java code, but just want to give it a try with mysql.

Comment: You need a basic course on SQL and DB design. Some practical info can be found here: http://www.kawoolutions.com/SQL_Database_Design

Comment: @Chan If you only have 4 players, then whether or not you need a `Player` table largely depends on whether or not you need to store changeable information for those players.  If not, just store the player ID and forget the secondary table.  If you have the table anyway, then yes, keep the key.

Comment: @Chan Regardless of whether you have a separate `Player` table: If you need to "check whether there is a player in a current node", then you do not need the `INDEX` on the key, as you are just looking at a field on a record you already know.  If you need to "find what node a player is in", then you should add the `INDEX`.

Comment: I added another boolean named "IsOccupied". Since I don't need to know if a particular Player in a Node, as long as there's a player there, I'm done. However I might have to change my implementation later, I'm still developing it. Thanks a lot for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

your tables could look like this

NODE
ID   POSITION FOOD-TAX TREASUREMAP PLAYER

PLAYER

ID_PLAYER   NAME_PLAYER

SO THE PLAYER OF NODE IS JUST THE FOREIGN KEY OF YOUR PRIMARY KEY ID_PLAYER OF THE PLAYER TABLE.

Decide whether in every node there would be a player always or it can be null.

Decide whether you want your table engine search be InnoDb or MyIsam. Your choice will depend whether it is a table which is going to be much more queried than updated or the other way around. If it is mostly be queried, choose MyIsam it is quicker. But in that case, know that MyIsam does not support Foreign Keys but you can beat that by creating an index instead and making the join through that. Sorry if I give you too much info, but these were things you were going to come across anyway.

Have a nice day

Al

Comment: Thanks Alvaro! By the way, are your from cpp-home.com?

Comment: you are welcome. No, I am not from the site c ++. Regards, Al